# R Decrease memory limit

Tags: r, memory-limit

I know it's easily possible to increase the memory limit of R using the command memory.limit(size=N). If I try to decrease it to a value smaller than N, for obvious reasons I get the error:

```
Warning message:
In memory.limit(size = 10) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

Is there a way to decrease the memory limit upfront running code (or as first command)? I want to implement this for training purposes (how to deal with memory issues?).

Answer (score 6):

From the fact that you are using `memory.limit` I assume that you are under Windows. If not, see `?'Memory-limits'`.

You can start R (from the command line) with the `--max-mem-size` switch. For example,

```
R --max-mem-size=50000000
```

gives a limit of approximately 50MB.